# how to append a <hr> to a form element selected in JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, append

Some introduction:
I'm creating a form in Django.
In my template I'm trying to select the final element of that form and attach a `<hr>` html element to help clean up the visual clutter.

I've tried selecting the Forms ID and inserting adjacenthtml as well as appending raw html. I have also tried passing raw html into bootstrap in my form but this has also failed to render.

tldr; I am trying to append a `<hr>` element to something I am targeting in Jquery

```
function addHoriztonalRule() {
            document.getElementById("form").insertAdjacentHTML(
                "<hr>");
        }
```

Comment: .insertAdjacentHTML() requires two parameters: position and text. A documentation is here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML

Comment: Just curious, if you are using JQuery why are you using document.getElementById("form") and not $("#form")?  And is the id of the form really form?

Comment: Phil Cowan, I changed the names of the items to make them more understandable/readable for Stack Overflow. Artisan, I had the parameter initially listed and removed it as it was not rendering & tried without it just throwing stuff at the wall which is what you see here. I do appreciate the input though. Thank you both for taking the time.

Answer (score 0):

With jquery you can use this:

```js
function addHoriztonalRule() {
    $('#form').after("<hr>");
}

addHoriztonalRule();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="form">
  <input type="text" value="hi" >
</form>
```

However, it is better to share the structure of the page to learn more from DOM and how to call the function to better guide

Comment: You're a lifesaver man, this worked flawlessly for what I was trying to do. Really appreciate it.

Comment: I'm glad you found it useful

Answer (score 0):

You failed to add the ***position*** of where you wish to place the HTML *in relation to* the element.

MDN: A DOMString representing the position relative to the element; must be one of the following strings:

1. '**beforebegin**': *Before the element itself*.
2. '**afterbegin**': *Just inside the element, before its first child*.
3. '**beforeend**': *Just inside the element, after its last child*.
4. '**afterend**': *After the element itself*.

```js
function addHoriztonalRule() {
  document.getElementById("form").insertAdjacentHTML('afterend', '<hr>');
}
addHoriztonalRule()
```

```html
<form id="form" method="post">
  <input type="button" value="button">
</form>
```